# iText7: how can I specify OpenType features to be used by a PdfFont?

Tags: pdf, itext7, opentype

For complex scripts (Tibt in my case) I need to be able to specify some OpenType features that a PdfFont should use (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/script-development/tibetan) for the ones to use with Tibt). I can't find any way to specify that to iText, and with the default features, the result is not OK.

Example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    final String notoPath = "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansTibetan-Regular.ttf";
    final PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("tibttest.pdf");
    final PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
    final Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
    PdfFont f = PdfFontFactory.createFont(notoPath, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
    doc.add(new Paragraph("༄༅། །སྒྲུབ།").setFont(f));
    doc.close();
}
```

produces a PDF that looks like:

[image: Nok result]

while it should look like:

[image: Expected result]

Is there a way to specify a list of OpenType features to use?

Comment: Are you using pdfCalligraph? https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph
If yes, then you are an iText customer with a support contract, and I recommend that you contact iText Software directly. If no: you need pdfCalligraph to use OpenType features of complex writing systems like Tibt.

Comment: I indeed am not using pdfCalligraph, thanks for the pointer. Can you turn your comment into an answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the add-on pdfCalligraph? https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph

If yes, then you are an iText customer with a support contract, and I recommend that you contact iText Software directly.

If no: you need pdfCalligraph to use OpenType features of complex writing systems like Tibt. See extended examples on the linked website.
Because I don't see you loading a license key in your code, I assume that this is the case.

In case your particular language isn't yet supported by pdfCalligraph, we'll make sure to add it ASAP. But from the top of my mind I think that most Indic languages are supported. You can request a 30 day free trial license at https://pages.itextpdf.com/itext-7-free-trial-landing-page-1.html

Full disclosure: I am QA Engineer at iText Software.

Comment: Using pdfCalligraph under AGPL licence is possible? Or is it just have the commercial version?

Comment: pdfCalligraph is only available under a commercial license. Go to https://itextpdf.com/en/request-a-quote to request a quote.